# Is there a way to save TQDM console output to a file?

Tags: python, console, tqdm

I have been trying to save a **tqdm** progress bar from the **tqdm** Python library to a text file. I have tried redirecting **sys.stdout** and **sys.stderr** to a file:

[image]

However, only the output from **stdout** is saved (e.g. print statements), not the **tqdm** progress bars. The progress bars stay in the console.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: you don't have to open the same file two times - you can assing the same file `file handler` to `stdout` and `stderr`. On some systems you may even get error if you try to write to the same file using two different `file handlers`.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to redirect it to file. `tqdm` uses special char `\r` to move to the beginning of line and reprint new text but in file you will see `\r` and all text - old and new - for every change in progress bar - something like `[#   ]\r[##  ]\r[### ]\r[####]`. If you need some information from `tqdm` then maybe you should assing `callback` which it will execute periodically with current values and then you can save it in file without redirecting.

Comment: if I run `tqdm` with redirection `sys.stderr` then I get it in file. Maybe problem in different. Maybe `tqdm` gets `sys` in different moment (in different module) and it gets original value `sys.stderr`. Better create minimal working code with your problem - and then we can copy and run it to see problem and test some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow. I am running some simulations and I want to record the time statistics (iterations/second) that tqdm provides, in addition to the other things my program outputs. Are you getting the tqdm progress bars in your file when you redirect it with sys.stderr?

Answer (score 5):

If I redirect `sys.stderr` to file then I get `tqdm` in file.

```py
import tqdm
import time
import sys

fh = open('output.txt', 'w')  # one file for both `stdout` and `stderr`

original_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = fh
#original_stdout = sys.stdout
#sys.stdout = fh

items = 100

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(items)):
    time.sleep(0.1)

sys.stderr = original_stderr
#sys.stdout = original_stdout

fh.close()
```

or I can use `tqdm(..., file=fh)`

```
import tqdm
import time

fh = open('output.txt', 'w')

items = 100

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(items), file=fh):
    time.sleep(0.1)

fh.close()
```

But this file has something like this

```
  0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  1%|          | 1/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.98it/s]
  2%|▏         | 2/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.84it/s]
  3%|▎         | 3/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.87it/s]
  4%|▍         | 4/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.90it/s]
  5%|▌         | 5/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.92it/s]
  6%|▌         | 6/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.93it/s]
  7%|▋         | 7/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.93it/s]
  8%|▊         | 8/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.94it/s]
  9%|▉         | 9/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.94it/s]
 10%|█         | 10/100 [00:01<00:09,  9.94it/s]
 11%|█         | 11/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.94it/s]
 12%|█▏        | 12/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.94it/s]
 13%|█▎        | 13/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 14%|█▍        | 14/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 15%|█▌        | 15/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 16%|█▌        | 16/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.94it/s]
 17%|█▋        | 17/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 18%|█▊        | 18/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 19%|█▉        | 19/100 [00:01<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 20%|██        | 20/100 [00:02<00:08,  9.95it/s]
 21%|██        | 21/100 [00:02<00:07,  9.95it/s]
```

`tqdm` uses char `\r` to move to the beginning of line and print new text.
My editor on Linux display it as new lines but on Windows you may see it all in one line like

```
  0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ?it/s]\r  1%|          | 1/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.98it/s]\r  2%|▏         | 2/100 [00:00<00:09,  9.84it/s]
```

---

If you want to get finall value `it/s` then you would rather use `time.time()` and calculate it manually.

```
import tqdm
import time
import sys

items = 100

start = time.time()

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(items)):
    time.sleep(0.1)

end = time.time()

diff = end-start
items_per_second = items/diff

print(f'time: {diff:.2f} s | {items_per_second:.2f} it/s')
```

Result:

```
time: 10.09 s | 9.91 it/s
```

And this you can write to file using `fh.write()` or `print(..., file=fh)` or  redirecting `sys.stdout` or redirect when you run code in console/terminal

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

---

Comment: Very cool answer. Thank you. I would like to ask if there is a way to set a fixed length on the output.txt file. Because I am afraid about launching a very massive script that will write so much on the file that it became too big.

It would be nice to have a sort of widows telling you only the last output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
import tqdm
import time

fh = open('demo.txt','a')
inital_pos = fh.tell()

# This will run for a minute
for t in trange(120):
    fh.seek(inital_pos)
    time.sleep(0.5)

fh.close()
```

This behaves in a similar fashion to `\r` when using consoles as it resets the end of the file in every loop thus avoiding printing the progress bar in a new line evertime it is updated.